# How to make the first character of the word uppercase?

Tags: php

Is there any function in PHP to make the first character of the word uppercase,
or should I write it by regular expression?

Comment: I typed 'php upper', and Google suggested I search for 'php uppercase first letter'. First hit is the ucfirst function. Google, then ask ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [ucfirst](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function.

Comment: On a side note ucfirst relies on locale so watch your step

Answer (score 4):

```
$word = ucfirst($word);
```

Answer (score 1):

$`firstlettersuppercased = ucwords($originalstring);`

This will capitalize the first letter of every word in the $originalstring.

Answer (score 1):

```
$word_ = "your name here";
echo ucfirst($word_); // Your name here
echo ucwords($word_); // Your Name Here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ucwords()` function.

Comment: ucwords() will capitalize each word in the string, not just the first letter. Maybe that is what the original poster wanted, not sure. Voted up for benefit of the doubt.